# Google Cloud Storage Client Library - Check Shared Publicly By Default

Tags: acl, cache-control, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am using Google cloud storage client library for uploading files into it dynamically and serving the files from it. The uploading part is working fine. There is no problem in that.

The issue i am facing is after upload if I try to access the file in my application, the serving link is broken.

So i went to Google cloud console and one thing i noticed is the Shared Publicly is unchecked.

If i check the Shared Publicly checkbox, then i could access the file in my application.

I have tried with both public-read and bucket-owner-full-control ACL.

This is the code I am using..

```
GcsFileOptions options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder().cacheControl("public, max-age=31536000, no-transform").mimeType(mimeType).acl("bucket-owner-full-control").build();
```

Can you guys tell us what modification should i make, to check that Shared Publicly checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the file to be publicly available? If so, why not set the ACL to public-read instead of bucket-owner-full-control?